# Store Jenkins workspace in Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am running Jenkins slaves (Windows) on AWS. We usually automatically turn off the machine after a few minutes the build is complete to save money.

We have a need (now) to save the workspace for some branches. I would like to know what the best strategy and commonly used. Keep it with the slave machine and start it as needed or copy the workspace to Artifactory?

Comment: Artifactory seems a strange place for it. Can't you upload the workspace to S3 after a succesful build and load it again from there?

Comment: @lvthillo I could but I would like to see what others do...since using jenkins pipelines allow me to build from any branches...I need a place to store some workspaces instead of keeping the slave up for long on AWS.

Answer (score 3):

How about you zip workspace and push it to Artifactory as the last step of your build.